# How do I create a bash script that sums any number of command line arguments?

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic

How would I create a bash script that the user can use to sum any amount of command line arguments? For example, say my script is called sum:

```
sum 3
```

3

```
sum 3 5
```

8

```
sum 9 8 21
```

38

And so on.. I realize that I will have to loop through the command line arguments and increment them to the total, but I am not really sure how to do that. I am not sure how to reference say the 2nd command line argument to a specific variable or how to get the number of total command line arguments.

Comment: The native `bash` feature won't handle floating point values (eg: 3.5). For that you'd need to use a program such as `awk`, `python`, `dc`, `bc` or `perl`. See @rici's answer.

Answer (score 15):

No need for `bash`, plain `sh` will do as well:

```
#! /bin/sh -
IFS=+; echo "$(($*))"
```

`$*` in POSIX shells, expands to the list of positional parameters (in this case, the arguments to the script) separated by the first character of `$IFS` (or space if `$IFS` is unset or nothing if `$IFS` is empty). `$((...))` is the shell internal arithmetic expansion operator (note that it supports decimal, octal and hexadecimal numbers)

If you need floating point support, that's where you'll need a different shell like `ksh93` or `zsh` (not `bash` as `bash` only supports integer arithmetic), though you could also use `awk`:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {t=0; for (i in ARGV) t+=ARGV[i]; print t}
```

That will use `long` (for integer) and `double` (for floating point) type numbers as implemented by your system. The input numbers must be decimal floating point or engineering notation in the English style (floating point delimiter is the *period* character regardless of the locale). With some `awk` implementations, it will fail if the first number is negative as `awk` would try to interpret it as an option.

Some `awk` implementations like GNU `awk` when POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment also support hexadecimals including with binary exponent notations. Or with `--non-decimal-data`, it understands octals and hexadecimals:

```
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 ./sum  0xap3 0xa
90 # (0xa * 2^3) + 0xa
$ awk --non-decimal-data -f ./sum  010
8
```

Comment: clever. But I really hope you are not confusing him ^^ It seems he's learning shell scripting basics, and you throw him IFS manipulation ^^ It's always good to know, but probably a bit too early for him...  Or provide explanations such as `IFS=+ means afterward the "$*" will expand to "all the arguments separated by a '+'", hence the $((computation)) will be replaced with the sum of all arguments`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following bash function:

```bsh
sum() {
    local sum=0
    for arg in "$@"; do
        (( sum += arg ))
    done   
    echo $sum
}
```

Comment: As a side question, is there a way to determine how many args are in the command line without looping?

Comment: `$#` is the number of args

Comment: Thank you, perfect. One last question I forgot to clarify.. is there any way I can detect if it is like the very first argument? So say it is the very first argument, I can do something special with it. For example, as a random example, if the very first argument is a 7, I echo that the very first argument is a 7.

Comment: @John `$1` is the first argument, `$2` is the second argument, and so on. The variable $0 is the script's name. The total number of arguments is stored in $#. The variables $@ and $* return all the arguments. See also: http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_read_command_line_arguments_in_a_bash_script

Comment: @John typically if you want to process the first argument differently you first copy it to something else and then shift all the rest of the arguments with `first=$1;shift`

Answer (score 8):

A non-looping variant:

```
{ printf %d+ "$@"; echo 0; } | bc
```

#### Example

Put the above in a script file, `sum`.

```
#!/bin/bash

{ printf %d+ "$@"; echo 0; } | bc
```

Run it like so:

```
$ ./sum 4
4
$ ./sum 4 4 5
13
```