# Script to count the number of numbers and letters in a file

Tags: shell-script

Hello guys I'm literally stuck in this damn - before exam exercise.

Exercise:
Write a scrypt wich gonna handle a name of a file ( as a first Argument ) and count amount of those numbers and letters in this file. 
Scrypt should also sum all of those numbers.

```
1 2 3 4 5
9 2 3 1 2 a l a i o l a 
9 2 ala ma kota 102
```

How it should looks like:

```
 File ....... have 15 numbers and 16 letters.
 Sum of all of those numbers is 145.
```

Mine idea how should I deal with this exercise(step by step)

1. catch the name of a file ( as an argument )
2. Parse the whole data into one line ( for easy sort )
3. Numberic sort for whole data ( to get result like this 1 2 3 4 5 6 (...)102 a a a a a a a i k m (...)
4. Set up first numbers as Arguments ($1-$13) for easy sum & count+ set up letters as Arguments for easy count
5. Pop everything into console
6. Enjoy mine life and play overwatch ( joke, getting back 2 learning Linux {lovely before exams stuffs } )

   Stuff on wich I'm stuck.

   Step 2.  After parsing those data im getting ( tried literally everything wich I could find ):

   ```
   1 2 3 4 5 9 2 3 1 2 a l a i o l a 9 2 ala ma kota 102
   ```

Truelly don't know how to merge those 3 lines into 1 line, whenever im trying 2 sort i'm getting back into the beginning.

```
echo `cat kolos3 | xargs | sort -n `
```

Would be great if any of you guys would be able to help me with this exercise.

Comment: I would do the opposite: `tr ' ' \\n` to have them one per line. Then it's easier to count - with a tool like `awk` - how many lines with letters (and sum their length) and how many with digits (and sum their values).

Comment: ... or even just awk with its record separator set to any sequence of one or more whitespace characters `[ \t\n]+`

Comment: Either you did not reproduce precisely your assignment or the assignment is incorrect: the sample output contains the number of digits in the input file and the sum of numbers. Numbers and digits are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -o` will do most of the work here, whether you join the inputs onto the same line or not.

> **-o, --only-matching**
>                 Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

To count the letters:

```
grep -o "[[:alpha:]]" "$file" | wc -l
```

To count the *digits*:

```
grep -o "[[:digit:]]" "$file" | wc -l
```

But if you instead want the *numbers*:

```
grep -o "[[:digit:]]\+" "$file" | wc -l
```

To sum the numbers, you could use any of the solutions on [How do I create a bash script that sums any number of command line arguments?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98907/how-do-i-create-a-bash-script-that-sums-any-number-of-command-line-arguments)

I would pass that problem to `bc`:

```
(grep -o "[[:digit:]]\+" "$file" | tr '\n' + ;echo 0)|bc
```