# Script to take arguments, sum numbers

Tags: linux

I'm trying to complete a script that will take 3 numbers from the command line and sum them, then display the output as "1 + 2 + 3 = 6". Here's the code I have:

```
clear
echo
for count
do
echo -n "$count + "
done
echo
echo
echo
echo All Done
```

I can make it output "1 + 2 + 3 +", but can't figure out how to get rid of the last plus or have the " = 6".

Answer (score 2):

Building on [a solution to one of many similar questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98934/116858):

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS=+
printf '%s = %s\n' "$*" "$(($*))"
```

- `"$*"` will expand to the positional parameters (the command line arguments), separated by `$IFS`.  We set `IFS` to `+` separately.
- `"$(($*))"` uses `$(( ... ))`, which is an arithmetic substitution, to evaluate the arithmetic value of `$*`, the command line arguments with `+` in-between them.
- `printf` is used to output the two strings with a `=` between them.

Testing:

```
$ ./script.sh 1 2 3
1+2+3 = 6
$ ./script.sh -1 2 3
-1+2+3 = 4
$ ./script.sh 1 2 3 4 2 2 3 1
1+2+3+4+2+2+3+1 = 18
```

What's missing in the script above is a validation of the supplied command line arguments to make sure they are integers.  This is done for one value in the question "[Checking if an input number is an integer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151654/checking-if-an-input-number-is-an-integer)".

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/gawk -E
BEGIN {
  sum = 0
  if (ARGC > 1) {
    for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) {
      n = strtonum(ARGV[i])
      printf "%s", i == 1 ? n : n < 0 ? " - " (-n) : " + "n
      sep = " + "
      sum += n
    }
    print " = "sum
  }
}
```

- That should accept floating point (but not `inf`, `nan` or things like `0x1p6`), hexadecimal and octal numbers
- For each argument, only the leading part (ignoring blanks) that can be interpreted as a number is considered.
- Note that the locale is honoured for the decimal-point (`.` in English, `,` in many other languages).
- Floating point numbers are printed as if using `printf("%.6g")` and integers as if using `printf("%d")`. Internally, `gawk` uses your C compiler `double` and `long` types internally, but with recent versions can be told to use arbitrary precision  with the `-M` option and  the `PREC` variable.

```
$ locale decimal_point
.
$ that-script 1.23 -1e2 0x30 010 garbage
1.23 - 100 + 48 + 8 + 0 = -42.77
```